# How do you show that the user is authenticated after they authenticate with Facebook?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, passport-facebook

I'm following [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-facebook) tutorial, implementing Facebook authentication with Node and Passport.

Both the tutorial and the [docs](http://passportjs.org/docs/facebook) say to do this:

```
router.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login'
  })
);
```

But then how does the user know whether or not they're authenticated? I'd like to send data to my front end that shows whether or not the user is logged in, and that I could use to update, say my navbar.

From what I understand, the process of authenticating with Facebook works like this:

1. Send out `GET /auth/facebook` request.
2. Hits route.
3. `304 Redirect` send back with url to the Facebook portal.
4. Send out request to Facebook portal with callback url.
5. User clicks "accept" on the portal.
6. Facebook sends back a `304 Redirect` with the url being your callback url.
7. Request is sent out to your callback url, which in this case is `GET /auth/facebook/callback`.
8. The `cb` of `passport.use(obj, cb)` gets run.
9. A `304 Redirect` is sent back, with the url being `/` or `/login` depending on success or failure.
10. A request is sent out to `/` or `/login`.

I'm not sure how I could update my front end with the logged in user.

```
router.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook'),
  function(req, res) {
    var userCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.user));
    delete userCopy.auth;
    res.status(200).json(userCopy);
  }
);
```

This doesn't work because there isn't a `$http.get().then()` that receives the data.

---

I tried adding in some query parameters:

```
successRedirect: '/?foo=bar'
```

But it's not working for me. The url bar says `http://localhost:3000/?foo=bar#_=_` and this doesn't log anything:

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  var url = path.resolve(__dirname + '/../client/' + envFolder + '/index.html');
  res.sendFile(url, null, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }
    console.log('here');
    console.log(req.query);
    return res.status(200).end();
  });
});
```

It works when I do `successRedirect: '/home?facebook=true'`. But inside of `sendFile`, I can't send anything *else* back. If I try `res.send('Authenticated with Facebook')` it gives me this error: `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`. Presumably because `sendFile` is sending back the file and setting some headers, and *then* I try to send something *else* back with different headers. So I'm not sure what to do.

---

The approach I arrived at is to use the `run` block:

```
function run($http, Session, $cookies) {
  $http
    .get('/current-user')
    .then(function(response) {
      Session.setUser(response.data);
      $cookies.put('userId', response.data._id);
    })
  ;
}
```

1. I'm not sure that this is the best approach.
2. It messes my tests up because they're not expecting the HTTP request and it sets the Session and cookies when I don't always want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could render the user object in the view, so you can get it via Angular checking the presence of the variable:

```
router.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook'),
  function(req, res) {
    var userCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.user));
    delete userCopy.auth;
    res.status(200).render('index', {user: userCopy});
  }
);
```

Your HTML index file should have:

```
<!--Embedding The User Object-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var user = <%= user | json | safe %>;
</script>
```

And finally your AngularJS app should have a service like this:

```
// Authentication service for user variables
angular.module('users').factory('Authentication', [

    function() {
        var _this = this;

        _this._data = {
            user: window.user
        };

        return _this._data;
    }
]);
```

Inject Autenthication service in your main controller and play with the user object:

```
angular.module('core').controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'Authentication',
    function ($scope, Authentication) {
        $scope.authentication = Authentication;
    }
]);
```